# Query with 3 tables and a MAX

Tags: php, mysql

I have these following tables:

```
Table "Questoes";
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field    | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id       | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_quest | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| questao  | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nivel    | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| tipo     | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

Table "Resultados";

+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type    | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id        | int(11) | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_user   | int(11) | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| nivel     | int(11) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| pontuacao | int(24) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data      | date    | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-----------+---------+------+-----+---------+----------------+

And table "utilizador";
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field     | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id_user   | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| id_tipo   | int(11)      | NO   |     | 1       |                |
| username  | varchar(50)  | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| password  | varchar(20)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| nome      | varchar(50)  | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| email     | varchar(100) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| data_nasc | text         | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| e_valido  | smallint(6)  | NO   |     | 0       |                |
+-----------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

What i need is the maximum of score (field "pontuacao") of each level (field "nivel") in the table "resultados" to the best player.
To get the players name, will be through the field "id_user" in table "resultados".

I have this, but doesn'st work:

```
SELECT u.id_user, MAX(u.pontuacao), u.nivel, u.data, l.nivel, r.id_user, r.username
FROM questoes l, resultados u, utilizador r
WHERE u.nivel = l.nivel AND r.id_tipo=1 AND u.id_user=r.id_user
GROUP BY u.nivel
```

Comment: When you say it doesn't work, what do you mean?  Does it throw an error?  Give unexpected results?

Comment: you have to include all fields apart from `u.pontuacao` in the group by at the end...

Comment: What do you get when you run your query?

Comment: The values ​​were incorrect. The user "StevieG" I have already answered correctly. TY

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT a.id_user, r.username, b.pontuacao, b.nivel
FROM resultados a
INNER JOIN utilizador r on a.id_user=r.id_user 
INNER JOIN (SELECT u.nivel, MAX(u.pontuacao) pontuacao
            FROM resultados u
            GROUP BY u.nivel) b ON a.nivel = b.nivel AND a.pontuacao = b.pontuacao
```

Comment: I was about to post almost the exact same thing. :)

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't work because you are relying on an extension to MySQL that doesn't do what you expect.  When using `group by`, just be sure all the columns in the `select` are either aggregated or in the `group by`.

What you want is more like:

```
SELECT u.id_user, r2.pontuacao, u.nivel, u.data, l.nivel, r.id_user, r.username
FROM questoes l join
     resultados u
     u.nivel = l.nivel join
     utilizador r 
     on u.id_user = r.id_user join
     (select r2.nivel, max(r2.pontuacao) as maxp
      from resultados r2
      group by r2.nivel
     ) r2
     on u.nivel = r2.nivel and u.pontuacao = r2.maxp
WHER r.id_tipo = 1
GROUP BY u.nivel;
```

This calculates the maximum value as a subquery and then joins it back in.  You may not need the `group by` after this.  Also, I fixed the joins so they use proper ANSI syntax.